# How do you say "vice versa" in Esperanto?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, translation

For example, I might say *I'll ask you the questions and you respond; then we'll do it again vice versa*, meaning that the second time around I would be the one responding to the questions.

Would *male* or *inverse* work, or is there already another common way to say this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use *inverse*:

> *Mi faru la demandojn kaj vi respondu, kaj poste/refoje inverse.*
>
> *Mi faros demandojn al kiuj vi respondu, kaj poste ni interŝanĝu (rolojn).*

I wouldn't use *male* because that means "not so, on the contrary":

> *Mi ne faros demandojn, male! mi aŭskultos silente.*

Comment: Do people ever use malmale?

Comment: Wouldn't that just be *same*?